# MailKit for sending mails in .Net Core. An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, mailkit

Getting an error stating **An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**. When connecting to SMTP server. 
Mail is getting triggered properly on development environment but it does not get triggered on Production.

Comment: Hello, are you trying to do it from your server or locally?

Comment: From the server i.e. our production server. Locally it works fine.

Comment: Seems like you need to configure **server network config**. There are no problem with **asp.net** or **mailkit**

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your SMTP server is aborting your TCP/IP network connection.

There's nothing you can do about that in your program.

This is a problem with your network configuration.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Here's the log that is generated from the ProtocolLogger. Does this say that the connection is aborted by the SMTP server or my Application Server?                                                                          Connected to smtp://SmtpServer_Name:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 IP WhiteListed
C: EHLO [XX.XXX.XXX.XX]
S: 250-smtpedge-eu.ey.net Hello [XX.XXX.XXX.XX]
S: 250-SIZE 73400320
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250 CHUNKING
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready

Comment: in the production environment, the logging stops at  S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready. I am not able to understand these details in the logs. The logs generated on my development environment has lot more details like the from address, rcpt address , subject , data etc.

Comment: Based on this new information, seems likely that the issue is due to some sort of issue toggling into `STARTTLS` mode. Perhaps due to missing Certificate Authority SSL certificates in your production environment's X.509 certificate database.

Comment: I know its not recommended but i tried using the SmtpClient from the legacy Sytem.Net.Mail (in Dot Net Core) and to my surprise the email functionality has started working. I am not sure what's the issue with MailKit in our production servers but System.Net.Mail is working awesome in all our environments. so for the time being i will be going ahead with Sytem.Net.Mail for Mail notifications. Thanks everyone for your time and suggestions